# How to do pprint in a byte array type?

Tags: python, arrays

When logging into Kibana, my json was turned into a byte array like this:

From this:

```
[{"flight_id": "1181916", "flight_number": "VJ143", "departure_time": "2021-06-10 18:25:00+07:00", "arrival_time": "2021-06-10 20:35:00+07:00"}]
```

To this:

```
 "{\"status\":\"success\",\"countRows\":1,\"data\":[{\"item\":\"c2c\",\"value\":\"[{\\\"start_date\\\": \\\"2021-05-01 00:00:00\\\"}, {\\\"end_date\\\": \\\"2021-05-02 23:59:59\\\"}]\"}]}"
```

Well I want it looks pretty like `pprint` in a byte array type:

My expected result:

It should be like this:

```
[\n\t{\n\t\tflight_id: 1181916, \n\t\tflight_number: VJ143, \n\t\tdeparture_time: 2021-06-10 18:25:00+07:00, \n\t\tarrival_time: 2021-06-10 20:35:00+07:00\n\t}\n]"
```

To look like this:

```
 [
    {
        flight_id: 1181916, 
        flight_number: VJ143, 
        departure_time: 2021-06-10 18:25:00+07:00, 
        arrival_time: 2021-06-10 20:35:00+07:00
    }
]
```

I wonder it there is any existing library helping me doing this.

Answer (score -1):

If printing this string is the only thing you are interested for, you can do just `print(your_string)` . It's preformated (with the \n and \t special characters) the way you want it .